# Getting password from AWS Secret Manager using IAM with PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, key, amazon-iam

I am quite new to the AWS infrastructure. I would like to get the MySQL password from the AWS Secret Manager. I have read that it is recommended to use IAM instead of storing the credentials on the webserver. Unfortunately I did not find a code example how I can access it. What are the actions I have to do?

My current approach without the IAM connection is this:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\SecretsManager\SecretsManagerClient; 
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

$client = new SecretsManagerClient([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'eu-central-1',
]);

$secretName = 'WebApp/App/MySQL';

try {
    $result = $client->getSecretValue([
        'SecretId' => $secretName,
    ]);
```

How can I add the IAM connection to the code? And which role do I have to create to get the SQL connection data from Secrets Manager?

Comment: if this is an EC2 instance eg, there's the concept of an assumed role, you then apply the permission to access your secret to that role that the EC2 operates under.

Comment: I have created an IAM role for the EC2 server, attached it to the EC2 instance. Now I added the Secret ARN from Secret Manager to the variable $secretName and get the value. But is this way right? Should I enter the Secret ARN from Secret Manager or Secret ARN from IAM? And how can I make sure that an attacker cannot access the password if the attacker has access to the server?

Comment: in IAM you grant access to the secrets ARN for that role